# Hi, I have a question regarding classes and constructors

Tags: oop, c++17

```
class Stack {
    private:
    int stackstore[100];
    int SP;
    public:
        Stack(void) { SP = 0; }
    void push(int value);
    int pop(void) {
         return stackstore[--SP];
     }
};

void Stack::push(int value) {
    stackstore[SP++] = value;
}
```

In this case I want to understand what difference it makes initializing SP in the constructor to  doing it directly when declaring the variable. Why is it a better practice to do it the way depicted above rather than this way (without the constructor) ->:

```
class Stack {
    private:
    int stackstore[100];
    int SP = 0;
    public:
        
    void push(int value);
    int pop(void) {
         return stackstore[--SP];
     }
};

void Stack::push(int value) {
    stackstore[SP++] = value;
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help :)

Comment: in your example it doesn't make much difference. But as the code scales, initializing it in constructor is a better practice.

Comment: Thank you khashayar amini! that is what I wanted to know. I guess it has something to do with memory allocation or code readability and reusability? Idk

Comment: @hash I disagree: http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-default